# How to run a setup from another setup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, command-line, windows-installer

I have a solution with 3 modules. Windows, Web, and Windows Service. I want to create one parent setup that runs three child setup packages regarding to the user choose.

I created a setup project as the following:

- I created a library that contains InstallerHelper which is inherited from `Installer` class
- I added the following code:

---

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);
    try
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string sProgram = Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, "Setup1.msi");

        Process p = Process.Start(sProgram);
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Context.LogMessage(exc.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the windows installer refuses to run multiple instances of windows installer and throws the following error:

> Another installation is in progress. You must complete that
>   installation before continuing this one.

Is my approach correct? Is ther another way to run another setup and the parent setup should wait all of them with one **Finish** click?.

Comment: You would normally create one setup with 3 *features* which can be optionally installed. Details of exactly how to do that vary depending on what setup technology you're using.

Comment: The problem is one of them windows and the other is Web. I'm not sure if one setup approach is a possible option

Answer (score 3):

You can use Wix Burn to create a setup package contained multiple application installers (msi/exe):

- [Wix Toolset: Building Installation Package Bundles](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm)
- [Neil Sleightholm's Blog: WiX Burn – tips/tricks](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.ru/2012/05/wix-burn-tipstricks.html)